# how to get the value in a particular div once the event is triggered in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am new to laravel and vue.js. I am fetching data from API using resources. The idea is am using 2 div's  **GOAL** and  **VALUE**.

The Value should be updated when there is a change in the value from the server through PUSHER..
without refreshing the page.
here is my code

1.**model**

```
class Progress extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name', 'goal', 'description'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

2.**Controller**

```
class ProgressController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      return ProgressResource::collection(Progress::paginate(4));
      event(new UpdatedValue());

}
}
```

3.**Resource.php**

```
class ProgressResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return[
         'the_custom_id' => $this->id,
         'name' => $this->name,
         'goal' => $this->goal,
         'description' => $this->description,
         'value' => ProgressResource::mockData($this->goal),
  ];
    }

 public static function mockData($goal=1000)
    {
        // 0 to $goal takes 17 minutes
        $multiplier = ($goal + 7) / 1000;
        $count = substr(time(), -3);
        return intval(round($multiplier * $count, 0));
    }


}
```

4.**Events**

```
class UpdatedValue implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public  $value, $goal;


    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($value)
    {
      //$this->progress = ProgressResource::collection(Progress::paginate(4));
        $this->value  = ProgressResource::mockData($this->goal);

    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('progress');
    }

}
```

5.**Components/Front.vue**

```
<template>
 <div class="container">
    <h1> Progress </h1>
       <div  class= "progress"  v-for = "progressdata in progress" v-bind:id="progressdata.id">
              <div id="div1">{{ progressdata.goal }}</div>
              <div id="div2" class="value">{{ progressdata.value }}</div>
        </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    data: function() {
            return {
              progress: [],
              
           }
        },
 mounted() {
       this.loadContents();
       this.listen();
 },

methods: {
    loadContents: function() {
           //load Api
           axios.get('/api/progress')
           .then((response) => {
                this.progress = response.data.data;
               
         })
         .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
    });
  },
    listen(){
      Echo.channel('progress')
          .listen('UpdatedValue', (e) =>{
            this.value = e.value;

            console.log(this.value);
            //console.log(e);
    });
    }
}
}
</script>
```

6.**BLade.php**

```
 <div id ="app">
      <front-page ></front-page>
      </div>
      <script src = "{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>

    </body>
```

Once the event has been triggered, the value should be updated in the front end without refreshing the page. I have installed **PUSHER PACKAGES , PUSHER-JS AND Laravel Echo THROUGH NPM**.I couldn't get the value which is updated through event in the front end..Could anyone help to solve this issue?.

Thanks.

Comment: you are using this inside a callback function. You should store this in some other variable then access that variable inside callback function

Comment: Couldn't get your answer sir, Could you please brief it? Thanks for your reply..

Comment: `this.value = e.value;` as far as I see "value" is not declared inside the `data()` Object, so it won't be reactive.

Comment: can you console this.progress object in callback where you initialize it . Does it show undefined ?

Comment: no, I  could get the entire  **Progress array**   after console.log(this.progress) inside the **load contents Function**.

Comment: @stockafisso I have to Initialize value in data object too ..

Answer (score 0):

```
loadContents: function() {
       //load Api
       let self = this ; // we are storing VueComponent object here.Cause this wont work in callback it will be undefined.
       axios.get('/api/progress')
       .then((response) => {
            self.progress = response.data.data;
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
});
```

> You didn't define value in data properties. Define Value there and use self object to store this(object).

```
data: function() {
        return {
          progress: [],
          value:null,
          
       }
    },
```

Comment: Sir, I have tried the same but I couldn't get the value updated ..I need the updated value  from server should be appended to the front.vue .. How could I go that? Could you please help me ..Thanks for your support..

Comment: can you share the console log and also do you use Vue dev tools to inspect current component ?

Comment: sure sir ,this is ,my  console(this.progress) 4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
0:
description: "Sunt quasi cumque aut error non qui iste."
goal: 54974
name: "Quaerat voluptas."
the_custom_id: 1
value: 39037 .. I don't use Vue dev tools to inspect current component.